# How can I automate this nginx rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I'm afraid I'm in way over my head. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but it's not clicking together so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've got a domain that hosts a number of micro sites, structured like so:

- domain.com/site1
- domain.com/site2
- domain.com/site3
- ...

I'm converting over from Apache to Nginx. When I was using Apache, this is the set of rewrite rules that worked for as many folders as I wanted.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2index.php [QSA,L]
```

At this point, I am able to get the sites working using individual rules. But it's not really a feasible solution for my circumstance.

```
location /site1 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /site1/index.php?$args;
}
location /site2 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /site2/index.php?$args;
}
location /site3 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /site3/index.php?$args;
}
```

There's gotta be a better way. I'm just such a noobie with Nginx, I can't quite figure it out. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you describe what is doubt you more specific? Oh, get it you want to automate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution here: https://github.com/rtCamp/easyengine/issues/31

```
set $dir "";
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^/]*)/.*$ ) {
  set $dir1 /$1;
}
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/  $dir1/index.php?$args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading a reply on my first answer I've changed it to this, don't know if you'll need the `$suburi` but it's there just in case.

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  index index.php; # need this
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }
  location ^~ (?<subfolder>/[^/]+)(?<suburi>.+) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $subfolder/index.php$is_args$query_string;
  }
}
```

Alternative with no named capture blocks

```
  location ^~ (/[^/]+)(.+) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $1/index.php$is_args$query_string;
  }
```

Comment: In apache rules for sites he has rewrite rule ^$ to index.php. So in that case server return 404, but it must return page generated by site1/index.php. For ex. /site1/nginx/automation/

Comment: ok i understand what you meant, ill edit my answer, didn't really understand what all the `#`'s meant in the apache rewrite

Comment: I didn't understand these `#` too. It's nice to be pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for putting this together. It looks like exactly what I need. Unfortunately when I add this to my config I get an error:
`Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown "subfolder" variable`

I'm running nginx 1.2.1 on Debian 64bit

Comment: ok then try to remove the named capture blocks and use numbers instead, I'll write the alternative in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think about something like these:

```
location ~ ^/(.*)/*.*$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php?$args;
}
```